# Как реализована система диалогов VK?

Tags: php, javascript, база-данных

По какому принципу ВК идет получение сообщения? Допустим отправить легко - написать сообщение, через ajax добавить в БД, а как в этот момент сделать, чтобы другому пользователю пришло это сообщение, не обновляя страницу? Есть ли возможность сделать такое не с помощью интервала, а именно тогда, когда сообщение добавляется в БД?
Если не сложно, прикрепите пример, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-хорошему, в современности, такое надо бы реализовывать с помощью WebSockets. Но во Вконтакте сделано иначе, еще со старых времен, когда вебсокеты были не такими удобными.

У них сделано так, что яваскрипт делает запрос на сервер, а сервер "зависает", в цикле проверяя наличие новых сообщений. Если сообщение появляется, сервер "развисает" и возвращает ответ. Благодаря этому нет временной задержки между отправкой сообщения и его получением (кроме, естественно, неизбежных сетевых задержек).

Если же новых сообщений не поступало в течение какого-то времени (20 секунд кажется), то скрипт тоже делает возврат, после чего яваскрипт тут же делает новый запрос, и все повторяется.

Comment: т.е. они свой вебсокет сделали такой по сути?

Comment: Откуда инфа про вк о_О. Сокеты создавались для передачи сообщений, они не могли быть неудобными или бесполезными ибо они для этих целей создавались и оптимизировались. Циклить и проверять - это затраты громадные даже если 1 раз в секунду цикл, 1 раз в секунду - отправляется запрос в БД там вычисления, и т.д. а когда таких чатов больше сотки это уже накладно будет.

Comment: В вк в среднем 5 000 000 онлайн. даже если 10% пользователей отправляют сообщение и сервер зависает в цикле на 20 секунд. То есть он делает.
500 000 * 20 = 10 000 000 запросов к базе. Я думаю там бы все полегло с таким подходом. Попробуй сам хотя бы 5000 запросов к базе сделать в цикле за секунду. А потом увеличь это число хотя бы в десять раз.

Answer (score 1):

Ну обычно реализуются на веб-сокетах, я думаю гугл больше даст примеров и информации по этому поводу чем я :)

https://github.com/morozovsk/websocket - тут и **примеры** и ссылки на забровские топики где описано как куда и что.